# combine videoplayback+image target in vuforia

Tags: android, vuforia

I able to show 2 kind of 3D object on 1 marker in image target sample, but now could I combine video playback + imaget target using android, too many parameters confuse me.

any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 1):

First read carefully both vuforia SDK tutorials for image and video playback.
open  Imagetarget.cpp and update the finction Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_ImageTargets_ImageTargetsRenderer_renderFrame()
according to your functionality.
here you can add video playback code.
change this function:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_ImageTargets_ImageTargetsRenderer_renderFrame(JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
    //LOG("Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_ImageTargets_GLRenderer_renderFrame");// Clear color and depth buffer 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    enter code here
    // Get the state from QCAR and mark the beginning of a rendering section
    QCAR::State state = QCAR::Renderer::getInstance().begin();

    // Explicitly render the Video Background
    QCAR::Renderer::getInstance().drawVideoBackground();

    #ifdef USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1en`enter code here`ter code here`
    // Set GL11 flags:`enter code here`

}
```